# Multiprocessing SQLalchemy: how to select database connections from the connection pool

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm currently writing a scraper that makes use of multiprocessing for better performance. The way I constructed the program is that the child process of the multiprocessing function does the scraping work and creates its own sqlalchemy engine, which is used to write the scraped data to my database. This way I have effectively 10 or something scrapers working at the same time. Because I don't want to spam the server with commits, I currently only use the connection.execute command in the child process and have the transaction.commit after the multiprocessing part so all commands would be committed with one command. However, because this commit does not have the same connection as the connection.execute commands, it doesn't work. How can I loop through the connection pool and find/call the individual connections that are created so that those can be committed and after that closed?

A bit of pseudocode to make some sense of my story:
`

```
def scrapefunction(scrapeIDs):
    1. scrape info from sources
    2. create own SQLalchemy engine and database-connection
    3. process info into MySQL query
    4. use connection.execute to execute the query

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=20)
    results = pool.map(scrapefunction, scrapeIDs)
    1. somehow loop through list of open connections from child processes
    2. somehow call the needed connections and commit them
    3. close the connections
```

`
This code is written in Python 3.4.3 by the way.

Comment: I think you're operating under the incorrect assumption that committing frequently is bad. In fact, it's usually the exact opposite. Depending on the backend and various factors, a transaction can tie up more and more server resources, like locks, the longer it runs. So, don't worry about committing too often; doing it every time the function is called is fine.

Comment: By the way, creating an engine in each call creates a fresh connection every time, which can have significant overhead depending on how long `scrapefunction` runs. You may want to use the `initializer` parameter on `Pool` to create the engine once for each worker.

Comment: I figured out that committing once at the end of each child process was indeed also a very viable option, so I decided to implement the commit statement that way. Furthermore, I discovered that upon closing the connection, no engine.dispose statement was made, so the same connection (which was closed after the first process) was used, instead of creating new engines everytime. After implementing these 2 fixes, the script runs fine, thanks for helping!